# Find the local maxima and minima .

Tags: calculus, functions, derivatives, radicals, maxima-minima

Consider the function $ \large f(x)=-x^{\frac{2}{3}} (x-4) \ $ in domain $ \ [-4,4] \ $. Find the local maxima and minima .what is absolute maximum-minimum?

**Answer:**

I have found the only critical point $ x=\frac{8}{5} \ $

Using 1st-derivative test , I see that $ x=\frac{8}{5} \ $ is a local maxima.

So there is no minima.

**Am I right?**

Comment: According to [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/obvfssrdqe), you're right! Notice that  after the critical point the graph goes down and down, and that the function is not defined at $x=0$.

Comment: The function is defined at $ x=0 \ $

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The domain is $x>0$.

$$f'(x)=-\frac{5}{3}x^{\frac{2}{3}}+\frac{8}{3}x^{-\frac{1}{3}}=\frac{8-5x}{3x^{\frac{1}{3}}}.$$

We see that $f$ increases on $\left(0,\frac{8}{5}\right]$ and $f$ decreases on $\left[\frac{8}{5},+\infty\right)$.

Thus, $x_{max}=\frac{8}{5}$ and $f$ has no a local minimum point.

If you mean that $f(x)=-\sqrt[3]{x^2}(x-4)$ then the domain with our given is $[-4,4]$,
$$f'(x)=\frac{8-5x}{3\sqrt[3]{x}}$$ which gives that $x_{min}=0$

because $f$ decreases on $[-4,0]$ and $f$ increases on $\left[0,\frac{8}{5}\right]$.

Comment: But in domain $ [-4,4] \ $ , does $ x=0 \ $ gives local minima ?

Comment: @mabmath No! If we write $x^{\frac{1}{3}}$ then the domain is $x>0$. Otherwise, if we write $\sqrt[3]{x}$ then the domain is $\mathbb R$.

Comment: The function in fact has domain $\mathbb{R}$. Only its derivative is not continuous at $0$

Comment: @Cuteboy If $f(x)=-\sqrt[3]{x^2}(x-4)$ then the domain of $f$ is indeed, 
 $\mathbb R$. The domain of $f(x)=-x^{\frac{2}{3}}(x-4)$ is $(0,+\infty)$.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg I think $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is understood as $(x^2)^{\frac{1}{3}}$, so it is well defined for all real $x$.

Comment: @Cuteboy For $x>0$ you are right. What happens for $x^{\frac{2}{4}}$?

Comment: If you graph the function , then I think $ x=0 \ $ is local minima. Can you confirm that ? Thanks

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg To my best knowledge, $x^{\frac{2}{4}}$ and $x^{\frac{1}{2}}$ are different functions. It depends on how you define it.

Comment: @Cuteboy Do you really  think that it's good? By the way, there is a definition. If we wrote $x^{\alpha}$, where $\alpha\in\mathbb Q$, then $x>0$. If we want to work with function $f(x)=x^{\alpha}$ then it's better to assume that $x>0$ by definition.

Comment: @mabmath the function $f(x)=-\sqrt[3]{x^2}(x-4)$ has a local minimum for $x=0$ of course.

Comment: @MichaelRozenberg https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potenzfunktion, this is a wikipedia page in german, it gives a definition of $x^{\frac{n}{m}}$ for $n\in\mathbb{Z}_{\neq 0},m\in\mathbb{N}$, $m$ is odd. At least from the definition here I saw $x^{\frac{2}{3}}$ is defined on the whole $\mathbb{R}$. But if you have other definitions, it is totally ok, it is just definition difference.

Comment: @Cuteboy Under all definition must be possibility to work with new object. I gave you an example, why my definition (it's not only mine of course!) is good and your is bad. But you are right. It's just definition difference.